# Jmeter - find out when HTTP sample started taking high response time

Tags: jmeter, response

I have almost 2000 URLs for which I have to find out min, max and avg response time.

I can get it using the aggregate report listener.

Now we want to find out when one particular URL started taking high response time, example

`/index.html` was taking 2-3 seconds for the first 3 hours but at the start of the 4th hour, it started taking 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

To see when sampler started *taking high response time* use [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/)

[image]

This is a JMeter plugin so you must have [JMeter plugin manager installed](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Installation-and-Usage)

Comment: Yes, but there are few problems. `1.` Hard to read when you find out for 1 particular URL `2.` These dots (pointers) are hard to read

Comment: @paul 1. Click Rows tab and uncheck other URLs, 2. Click Settings tab and change `Group timeline values for 60000 ms